# Markov chain probability that a state changes

Tags: markov-chains

For the  Markov chain given below what is the best way to find the probability P{$x_n = x_{n-1}$} and 
P{$x_n \neq x_{n-1}$}

The transition matrix of the chain is
\begin{array}{}
1/3 & 2/3 & 0 \\
0 & 2/3 &  1/3 \\
0 & 2/3 & 1/3 \end{array}

Comment: Hello.  Do you know what the distribution of $x_{n-1}$ is?

Comment: i am sorry , i forgot to add that the initial distributions are given: P(x_0 = 0)= 1/2, P(x_0 =1)= 1/2 and P(x_0 = 2)=0.

Comment: Actually we don't care...

Comment: Why are you revising your question, omitting conditions that where previously specified?

Answer (score 2):

For every state $x$, $P(x_1=x\mid x_0=x)=\frac13$, hence $P(x_n=x_{n-1})=\frac13$ and $P(x_n\ne x_{n-1})=\frac23$, for every initial distribution and every $n$.

Comment: thanks, but what if the probabilities are not same, what do we do then (like they are 2/3 for $p_{00}$ and 1/3 for the rest)

Comment: This is another question: then one must compute $P(x_n=0)$ first, and that depends on the initial distribution.